# How Do I Convert This Raw SQL Into a sqlalchemy Query?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using the following query in MySQL. It's using 2 tables. One of the tables  is named sample_variable. It is aliased (as a and b) and joins on itself. The other table is named sample_fixed. The query works as expected as SQL. What I am looking for is the sqlalchemy version of this query. Any help is appreciated.

`SELECT a.row_id, a.field, a.value, b.field, b.value, sample_fixed.qno 
FROM sample_variable a join sample_variable b on a.row_id = b.row_id 
RIGHT OUTER join sample_fixed on a.row_id = sample_fixed.row_id
WHERE a.row_id = b.row_id AND a.field = 'age' AND a.value = 60 AND b.field = 'region' AND b.value = 3;`

Thank you in advance,
-RLS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = aliased(SampleVariable, name="a")
B = aliased(SampleVariable, name="b")
qry = (
    session.query(A.row_id, A.field, A.value, B.field, B.value,
                  SampleFixed.qno)
    .join(B, A.row_id == B.row_id)
    .outerjoin(SampleFixed, A.row_id == SampleFixed.row_id)
    .filter(A.row_id == B.row_id)  # @note: redundant: included in the JOIN above
    .filter(A.field == 'age')
    .filter(A.value == 60)
    .filter(B.field == 'region')
    .filter(B.value == 3)
)
```

Comment: Thank you, van. I this works beautifully and I can now move on with my project. Much appreciated.